# using command-line clang, OS X 10.9.1, Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: macos, clang, address-sanitizer

I'd like to use the -fsanitize=address features of clang.

I'm on:

```
OS X 10.9.1 with Xcode 5.0.2
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
```

I'm running clang from the command line, and I'm getting the error:

```
clang: error: unsupported argument 'address' to option 'fsanitize='
```

I'm told this works, but searching around hasn't shown me the way; do I need to bring in a different version of clang?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The out-of-box version of `clang` on `OS X` does not implement support of Address Sanitizer. You will have to build your own version of `clang` from sources.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different build of clang than the one apple gave you. The simplest way to get one (or more) is to install Homebrew http://brew.sh
and then

```
brew install llvm --with-asan
```

You could also try a prebuilt clang from http://llvm.org/releases/download.htm.
It's by no means impossible to build clang 'by hand', but last I checked it did take multiple checkouts to get the source tree. The other options should have you *asan*ing in minutes.

Comment: Update: Apple's Xcode is starting to come with builds of clang that have Address-Sanitizer enabled.